# Combine two jQuery functions new

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Please help me to combine two scripts of jquery. AT the moment they are not compatible to each other. What can I do to make them both friendly. 
Jquery:

```
<script>
function edit_product() {
var id = $('.DIVY.panel3').attr('id');
alert (id);
</script>

<script>
  $(function(){

    $('.DIVY').click(function(){
        $('.DIVY.panel3').removeClass('panel3').addClass('panel2'); 
        $(this).removeClass('panel2').addClass('panel3'); 
    })
})
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="1" class="DIVY panel2" >click me please!</div>
<div id="2" class="DIVY panel2" >click me please!</div>
<div id="3" class="DIVY panel3" >click me please!</div>
<div id="4" class="DIVY panel2" >click me please!</div>

<div ><a href="#" onclick="edit_product()">Check ID</a></div>
```

For better visualization, I put this code to [My_jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sirgenius/CevcR/1/) 
Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works on jsfiddle, just change the execution to `No wrap - <in head>` on the **Frameworks & Extensions** panel, see http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/CevcR/4/

But don't mix jQuery and inline js code if you can, you lose clarity in the code.

Assign an id to your anchor element like `editMe` and set its click function, your code can look like:

```
 $(function () {

     $('.DIVY').click(function () { // when a .myDiv is clicked
         $('.DIVY.panel3').removeClass('panel3').addClass('panel2');
         $(this).removeClass('panel2').addClass('panel3');

     })

     $('#editMe').click(function () { // when a .myDiv is clicked
         var id = $('.DIVY.panel3').attr('id');
         alert(id);
     })

 })
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/CevcR/2/